# ubuntu server becomes unreachable through ssh over time

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, ssh

I'm encountering an issue with my Ubuntu server where, after a reboot and some time has passed, I am unable to connect through SSH or ping the host. I could trigger github actions that could run on the host though.

Here's what I've tried without success:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

The server is running on an AMD Threadripper 1950 with an X399 Designare motherboard.

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"